# App Engine fetch from another app internally

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

Just from curiosity, is there a way in App Engine to fetch data from another App Engine app using some sort of an internal URL (similar to CloudSql connection)?

For example, instead of doing this:

```
urlfetch.fetch("https://my-app-id.appspot.com/url/to/fetch")
```

Do something like this:

```
urlfetch.fetch("/appengine/my-app-id/url/to/fetch")
```

Comment: Can't provide an answer of "No" so here it is a comment.  No there isn't. What is wrong with your original example.

Comment: If you need to get data directly from datastore you can try remote API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi

Comment: @TimHoffman thanks. Nothing is wrong with the first example. I'm just asking out of curiosity, as such thing exists for CloudSql.

Comment: @DevilingMaster That's a nice alternative and maybe you could write that in an answer.. which is of course No..

Comment: @DevilingMaster thanks, but I don't need to access the datastore.

Comment: I couldn't actually give a "No" answer without padding things out ;-)

Comment: :) Feel free to do that, I'll accept.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to access the data in the datastore or fetch a URL endpoint. The datastore does have [an API](https://developers.google.com/datastore/) and with the right authorization you can access it from anywhere. For URLFetch I don't understand, what's the issue in using the absolute path instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer data via Google Cloud Storage with [GCS Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/)

You just need to added the service account for sharing Google Cloud Storage to each other.

Simple use case in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cloudstorage as gcs

with gcs.open('your-bucket/your-file.txt', 'w') as gcs_file:
    gcs_file.write('hello world\n')
```

Once you shared the bucket to your projects, you can access the same file in specified bucket on every App Engine instance in different projects.

This is the easiest way to share data among different app engine project.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/#Python_Asserting_identity_to_other_App_Engine_apps), applications can message one another. Check the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` field for authorization.

Comment: This is only for identifying where the request came from, not sending messages. The sample on the documentation just filter app id for accepting requests.